# Healpy Mollview function returned nothing

Tags: healpy

I am a new healpy user. I used healpy tutorial available at page http://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html for creating a map but after execution of "healpy.mollview" command it returned nothing and no plot was visible. Need Help!

I have searched the problem already but unable to find the exact situation anywhere

Thanks,

Jibran

Answer (score 1):

For using `healpy` plotting functions, the best is to use `ipython`, in particular:

```
ipython --pylab
```

Comment: The `--pylab` flag isn’t recommended anymore; better to run ipython and then enter `matplotlib [inline|qt|osx|gtx]` (selecting the appropriate backend display for your system). See: http://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.ipynb.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to `show` the plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

as you would do for any plot in matplotlib